# what is android API level where was introduced Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android

In what API level was introduced Navigation Drawer? I tried to search and find what was introduced in API 14 but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know 14 is correct, but to make sure, try to implement a NavigationDrawer and set your APILevel lower than 14. Normally e.g. claims that at least lvl 14 is needed

Answer (score 4):

[`DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) is included in the v4 support library, so it can be used on  any platform version starting from API level 4.

The support library was specifically designed to bring newer features and ui patterns also to older device and provide a consistent user experience throughout the whole platform.

Comment: i need API level without support library

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: from support library I can't customize drawer list, cant set custom Array Adapter, work only with `android.R.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: Just add a ListView to the DrawerLayout, and set its adapter to an Array Adapter.

Comment: dont work , I get this error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file ` on older devices

Comment: That's a different problem then - the described principle will work. Post a separate question about that, with the full LogCat and xml.

Answer (score 0):

The *Navigational Drawer* is part of the suport library v4.

From the [Android doc:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html)

> Support android.app classes to assist with development of applications for android API level 4 or later.

So you can use the navigation lib from **api 4** onwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can check in this [link](http://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/navigation-drawer-android/)

As google  announced a new navigation pattern called Android navigation drawer. Along with guideline and sample which requires latest version of android support library v13